# Getting a "global name is not defined error" when making an "objects.get()" query

Tags: python, database, django

I'm getting the error that

> global name 'name' is not defined...

for the `subjects = Course...` line. I want to query the subject names so I can use them in the subjects template

Models

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Course(models.Model):

name      = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
 stype      = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
 subject   = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
 location  = models.CharField(max_length = 100) 

class Teacher(models.Model):
 username      = models.ForeignKey(User,unique = True)
 address   = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
 city      = models.CharField(max_length = 50)   
 email_address = models.EmailField(max_length=75, unique = True)

class Student(models.Model):
 username      = models.ForeignKey(User,unique = True)
 address       = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
 city          = models.CharField(max_length = 50)   
 email_address = models.EmailField(max_length=75, unique = True)


class Attendance(models.Model):

 course    = models.ForeignKey(Course,unique = True)
 student   = models.ForeignKey(Student,unique = True)
 teacher   = models.ForeignKey(Teacher,unique = True)
 date      = models.DateField(unique = True)
 status    = models.BooleanField(unique = True)
 created_at= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
 updated_at= models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

 def subjects(request,username):
    user      = User.objects.get(username=username)
    subjects  = Course.objects.get(name = name)
    variables = RequestContext(request,{
        'username': username,
        'subject' : subject
  })   
    return render_to_response('subjects.html', variables)
```

Comment: Variable titled `name` is not defined exactly at that line. What can be unclear here?

Comment: What do you expect the `name = name` to do?

Answer (score 1):

`subjects  = Course.objects.get(name = name)`  the `name` is not defined.

You can pass the `name` like `username` by function argument:

`def subjects(request,username, name):`

Or instead of `name` by other string , like :

`subjects  = Course.objects.get(name ="course_name")`

Comment: Shihongzhi i tried that def subjects(request,username, name): before posting the question and i got this subjects() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Comment: @CalinSinea seems like you have not studied django properly.

Comment: @CalinSinea You don't pass 3 argument to the function.I suggest you to read the `Django Document` or `Django Book`. And some tutorial about `python`

Comment: Made it work thanks , well yeah i am a begginer trying to as i go

Comment: @CalinSinea No thanks.Every people is from the beginner.If my answer helped you, you can accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `username` in `def subjects(request,username):` but..

```
subjects  = Course.objects.get(name = name)   ### name is not defined here...you have to get it from parameter just like username.
```

Comment: i know what you are saying but def subjects takes only 2 parameters i i cant use name as a parameter but i need it as a variable

Comment: Why? It can take as much parameter as you want, but if it is not mandatory, then you can set a default value like `def subjects(request,username, name=None)` like so, if you do not set `name` parameter on function call, then it will be set as `None` within the function